# Square of Double summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

In order to find the expected value of a random variable I need to simplify this sum:

$ \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{m-1}\sum_{i+1}^{m} a_{i,j}\bigg)^{2}$

I'm familiar with the well known formula for squaring a single summation, but I'm not sure how to expand this.

**Edit - added information**

$a_{i,j}$ can take values of 1 with probability $p_{1}$, and -1 with probability $p_{2}$.
The random variable I'm trying to find the expected value depends on the reciprocal of the above summation.

Comment: Could you provide more context, such as what you're trying to find the expected value of? As it stands, I'm not sure if the above can be simplified. Do you have an answer already?

Comment: @Clarinetist I've added some more information about $a_{i,j}$ please let me know if you think more info would be helpful

Comment: Do you have $p_1+p_2=1$ or can $a_{i,j}$ also be zero?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes they sum to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum is just the sum of all the $a_{i,j}$ with $j \gt i$.  There are $\frac 12m(m-1)$ terms in the sum.  As all the terms are $\pm 1$ the sum only depends on how many are positive.  If there are $k$ positive terms and $\frac 12m(m-1)-k$ negative terms the sum is $2k-\frac 12m(m-1)$.  The square is then $$4k^2-2km(m-1)+\frac 14m^2(m-1)^4$$
You can compute the probability of values of $k$ and use that to get the expected value.